# Not able to send push notification for Android messaging app?

Tags: java, android, spring-boot, push-notification, mesibo

We have developed an Android chat-app having Java Spring-boot as backend. We are using the Mesibo messaging platform. We need to develop a push notification feature. Also, we cannot use FCM as it is blocked in certain countries. **Mesibo** has provided a webhook and some events for sending a push notification.

**How will I deliver messages to the user when the app is closed on the phone or the user is offline? Also, I am not sure how the backend will receive the event on which callback will be sent to Mesibo?**

Answer (score 0):

If FCM is blocked in countries, you need to have alternate mechanism to wake up your phone, for example, Baidu.

Set up your webhook in the mesibo console so that mesibo invokes it when there is a message or call for an offline user. You can then use (say, Baidu push) to wake up the phone. Once the phone comes out of sleep, mesibo can take over.

Comment: Okay. How will I get to know that app is in active or sleep state? Should I handle it on the app end or from the backend?

Comment: If your app is active, mesibo will deliver the message and you don't need to do anything on your part. if your app is not active, your user will go offline and then mesibo will invoke your webhook.